# is there any way to run mongo scripts without having mongo shell installed?

Tags: linux, mongodb, powershell, shell, mongo-shell

Currently , I have an java mongo connector app that connects to mongo database and inserts a json file content into database.
I am planning to achieve the same using mongoimport command as part of a script .I would like to check is there any way that we can run mongo scripts without having mongo shell installed on the machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my question
mongoimport is part of the database tools package (which includes mongoimport, mongoexport, mongodump and mongorestore). You can find packages for all the operating systems here: https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/database-tools.

So the bottom line is in order to run mongo shell commands atleast  machine need to have mongo database tools installed

Answer (score 1):

To interact with MongoDB server you need some sort of a client that speaks the MongoDB wire protocol. The shell (technically, either of the two shells as of 5.0) is one such client. An application you write that uses a MongoDB driver is also a client that would work.

Since the wire protocol is binary, simple tools like netcat aren't going to work.

If the server allows remote access, you can use a client on any of the machines that is allowed to access the server.

Comment: so basicallyin order to run the command we need to have mongo shell installed . We  can't run these without having any client unlike the default linux cat / ls commands. Am i correct? pls confirm , so that i can accept the answer